# How to create Single abstract controller to inherit in other controllers

Tags: magento2, extensions, controllers, abstract-class

I would like to create a single abstract controller in which i will define my authorization code to check for user validity and want to inherit that controller in my other controllers, so that i don't need to write the same authentication code on every other controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple include your controller in other controllers in which you want to inherit your controllers methods.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth $auth
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_auth = $auth;
}
```

Now if your controller has any function like login($username,$password)

```
public function login($username,$password)
    {
       /* ----------
        Code
       */
    }
```

In that case you can use this function in any controller where you have injected the controller like above like -

```
public function execute()
{
    //example
    $this->_auth->login($username,$pwd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow Magento best practises, you would put your abstract controller into your module's `Controller/` directory, and inherit in a subdirectory, for example `Controller/Product/`.

Magento's catalog module has an example for that:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product.php` contains:

```
<?php

abstract class Product extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements ViewInterface {
[...]
```

and `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/View.php` contains:

```
<?php

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product {
[...]
```